# Detecting End of Voicemail AND Recording at same time (Asterisk)

Tags: record, asterisk, voicemail

Please consider this a desperate please for help!

We are building an app that records the outgoing voicemail message of dialed cell phones ONLY. When the outgong message on the dialed cell phone ends, we want to STOP CALL and NOT leave a message. WE ARE STUCK ON DETECTING THE END OF THE DIALED CELL PHONE NUMBERS OUTGOING VOICEMAIL MESSAGE! (We need to know when to stop recording so a blank message is not left on the phone of the dialed party.)

Asterisk AMD (Answering Machine Detection) works to detect the end of the outgoing voicemail on the dialed phone, BUT Asterisk does not let you record in AMD mode. WE NEED TO RECORD AND DETECT THE END OF THE DIALED CELL PHONE'S OUTGOING VOICEMAIL MESSAGE.

We'd be real grateful for anyone who has a break through.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Record() offers a max-silence timeout - just use Record() and have it end when there is more than X second of silence. Also, maybe if you were'nt yelling AMD would work properly :)